# Find middle index of a matrix inside a matrix python

Tags: python, matrix

i'm trying to find the start and stop of a matrix inside a matrix

For example theres a matrix of W and B, B is a square inside the whole matrix:

```
5 6
WWBBBW
WWBBBW
WWBBBW
WWWWWW
WWWWWW
```

i want to get the middle of:

```
BBB
BBB
BBB
```

which should output me:

```
2 4
```

because the matrix is in another matrix

My idea was to take the square and make the middle B1
then index it inside of the whole matrix.

I've tried the code as following which i made.

```
def middle(m):
    # for getting the middle of BlackPart
    n = len(m)//2
    n1 = len(m[n])//2
    m[n][n1] = "B1"
    return m

def find(matrix, list1):
    # for getting B list
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
            if matrix[i][j] == "B":
                list1.append("B")
                return list1

def q2():
    # for getting matrix
    nope = input("").split(" ")
    counter1 = 0
    m = []
    while counter1 < int(nope[0]):
        a = input("")
        m.append(list(a))
        counter1 += 1
    # for getting matrix

    # below is for getting a square matrix

    l = []
    find(m, l)
    n = int(len(l) ** (1 / 2))
    counter = 0
    for i in range(len(l) // 3):
        l += [l[counter * n: counter * n + n]]
        counter += 1

    middle(m)
q2()
```

But it was too complicated and confused me, then i ended up noting it as a failure.

Please tell me if there is an easier way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  "Give me code" is out of scope for this site, and is virtually guaranteed to get your post down-voted and deleted.

Comment: Why should the middle of:

BBB
BBB
BBB

output me:

2 4 and not B?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
As the posting guidelines tell you, "Make it easy for others to help you."  This includes using meaningful variables and providing an initial attempt at debugging.  "it confused me" is not a problem specification.

Comment: @Prune he tried and failed. That is valid. Give me code without trying would be invalid.

Comment: @PetrL. its because BBB BBB BBB is inside of the big function and im trying to find the index of the middle while its in the big matrix

Comment: @PetrL. This is not valid: any request to write an assignment from scratch -- or even a major portion thereof -- is out of scope.  "I have a bug in this line of my program; see the output trace" is a valid question.  "This doesn't work for some reason; give me something that works" is off-topic.  We fix specific coding problems; we are not a large-scale coding service.

Comment: @RobertWinton - What if the middle portion was BBBB, BBBB, BBBB, BBBB? What should the middle of this be? Also, are the Bs always going to be contiguous?

Comment: @Prune i'm sorry, i'm new, i'll go read the guildlines

Comment: @not_speshal then the middle should be BBBB BBBB BB-B-B BBBB (-B-) is marked and no its not contiguous

Comment: What is the output for the 4x4 B? You said it's 2 4 for the 3x3. 4x4 doesn't have *one* middle. Also, I don't understand what you mean by "(-B-) is marked and not its not contiguous"

Comment: @not_speshal the specific output should be adjusted to the matrix, if there is more W then the answer would adjust

Comment: @RobertWinton Then your example is incorrect. If we take x as as first and y as second, the result (countingfrom top) is 3,1

Comment: @PetrL. sorry, i forgot to mention, the answer would be 4, 2 because both nums would be added by 1

Comment: @PetrL. and order doesn't matter in the output

Comment: @RobertWinton why though, indexing starts from zero?

Comment: @RobertWinton Sure it does, you can't swap x and y just like that

Comment: @PetrL. it was kinda not a project im working on, but a question for homework and i actually don't know, it was just like that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235676/discussion-between-robert-winton-and-petr-l).

Comment: @PetrL. should i give you the full question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go, I figured it out:

```
matrix = """WWBBBW
WWBBBW
WWBBBW
WWWWWW
WWWWWW"""
bstart = 0
bend = 0
bfound = False
bposition_x = 0
bposition_y = 0
bstartline = 0
bfoundinlines = []
matrix = matrix.split("\n")
for linenum, line in enumerate(matrix):
    bfound = False
    for index, x in enumerate(line):
        if x == "B" and bfound == False:
            bstart = index
            bfound = True
            bfoundinlines.append(linenum)
        elif x == "W" and bfound == True:
            bend = index - 1
    bstartline += 1

bposition_x = int((bstart + bend)/2 + 1)
bposition_y = int(round(len(bfoundinlines)/2)) # 1 already added (counting from 1)
if len(bfoundinlines) == 1: bposition_y = 2 #python rounds 0.5 to 0
print("from top:",bposition_y,"from left",bposition_x)
```